# How to check whether a view is visible in specific area or not inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have one ScrollView inside my application, this ScrollView contains number of images in it, we have to scroll up to the bottom to view each and every image because the area of scrollview is more than the screen size.

Now the question is that how can I check that each image of ScrollView is inside a specific area(defined by me) or not.

If the image is inside that area I want to do something and if its not then I want to do something different.

Please help me to get out of the problem, any help would be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use image.getVisiblity().

Comment: it will just check he visibility of the view but i want to check the visibility of the view within a specific area

Comment: i'm not getting.. so you want to check visiblity of imageView inside the scrollView?

Comment: yes inside the ScrollView and within a specific area suppose if my screen height is 800 then suppose the specific area is from 300 to 400 and if it is within that area I should get a callback.

Answer (score 2):

See below code, Check is this working

```
public static boolean isInVisible(ScrollView scrollView, View view, Rect region, boolean relative)
{
    int top = scrollView.getScrollY() + region.top;
    int bottom = scrollView.getScrollY() + region.bottom;

    if(!relative)
    {
        // If given region is not relative to scrollView 
        // i.e 0,0 does not point to first child left and top
        top -= scrollView.getTop();
        bottom -= scrollView.getTop();
    }

    Rect rect = new Rect(region);
    rect.top = top;
    rect.bottom = bottom;
    Rect childRegion = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());

    return Rect.intersects(childRegion, region);
}
```

Comment: Great, but what should I put in for (Rect region), I am not familiar with this

Answer (score 0):

yes each imageinside the ScrollView is defined by you.so,you change any modifications inside yhe scroll view.if you have any specific need then post your code